# Como eu posso fazer para que o texto da print apresente de maneira mais lenta?(python)

Tags: python

A ideia é dar um delay no texto, não como o sleep, mas fazer os caracteres da frase apareçam numa determinada velocidade, ao invés de apresentar tudo de uma vez.

```
print('E lá vamos nós')
```

Existe um comando específico da linguagem para fazer isso ou incluído em um módulo?

Comment: Você não pode ir imprimindo um caracter de cada vez? Dando um sleep entre esses prints.

Comment: Seria inviável caso ele precise fazer usar isto mais vezes durante o programa , e também se o tamanho de caracteres fosse em grande número, imagina quantos sleep não iria precisar. O códico iria ficar muito confuso e bagunçado.

Comment: Eu testei aqui e aparentemente não é possível, não dá pra fazer isso que você tá tentando. Só uma linha por vez.

Comment: @G.Bittencourt, de uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/448808/137387

Answer (score 2):

Use o [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) para imprimir caractere por caractere e [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.sleep) para criar uma pausa entre cada caractere.

Nesse caso para `print` é passado o argumento `''` para o parâmetro `end` significando que ao final da impressão não será pulada uma linha.
Para o parâmetro `flush` é passado o argumento `True` pois print usa um buffer de saída e o parâmetro `flush` indica que esse buffer deva ser despejado ou não após a evocação do comando e um valor `True` indica que sim deva ser despejado. Se não fosse feito assim a impressão só seria feita após o término do loop que contém a instrução,

```
import time

def slowprint(texto, atraso=0.2):
  for c in texto:
    print(c,end='',flush=True)
    time.sleep(atraso)

slowprint('E lá vamos nós')
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/UnitedQuestionableAdministration

Comment: Você poderia me explicar o que o *flush=True* faz?

Comment: @G.Bittencourt, a função print usa de um buffer da dados para optimizar a impressão. Quando faz `flush=True` estou informando a função que descarregue imediatamente o conteúdo desse buffer na saída. Caso não fizesse a impressão só ocorreria quando terminasse o laço `for` que contém a função.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Perfeito, muito obrigado.